# bootstrap popover hide dont work on key event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

This backbone function works normally:

```
closeFeedbackPopover : function({
    this.$el.find(".openFeedbackPopover").popover("hide");
}
```

But, when its called by keypress, the popover is not hidden.

```
createFeedbackPopover: function() {
    var self = this;
    $("a textarea inside my popover").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            if($(this).val().trim() != "") {
                var feedback = new Feedback({
                    message : $(this).val(),
                    taskId : taskModel.get("id"),
                    instanceId : taskModel.get("processInstanceId")
                });
                feedback.save();

                $(this).val("");
                self.closeFeedbackPopover(); <-- here
                globals.messages.success(t("feedback_sent"));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I hope you are not calling the keypress function on this `$("a textarea inside my popover")`. Can you show the whole code, eventually to create a fiddle.

Comment: Hi Simo, thanks for answer. Yes, the keypress function are been called, 'a textarea insine my popover' is only a example. I create a gist to show a bit more: https://gist.github.com/jQuadros/7943df952f0b5f74a54890a6a9872198

Comment: Are you sure this function `self.closeFeedbackPopover();` is invoked?

Comment: Yes, the debug shows it, the line this.$el.find(".openFeedbackPopover").popover("hide"); is invoked too, but don't work.

Comment: can you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue.

Comment: can you post code where in you have called `createFeedbackPopover`or attached it as a listener